# appear another window not main window in Activity_main

Tags: android, user-interface, kotlin

i have problem with onStart()

when i run project i don't wanna appear layout of activity_main

i want start layout in class LogInActivity  on class OnStart()

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


var mAuth:FirebaseAuth?=null


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener {
        var intentToSignUp = Intent(this, SignUp::class.java)
        startActivity(intentToSignUp)
    }
}
```

i don't know why it's not working this class maybe i write some wrong in code

```
override fun onStart(){
    super.onStart()
    if (mAuth?.currentUser == null) {
        var intentToLogin = Intent(this,LogInActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intentToLogin)
    }
}


}
```